Understanding (plane) curves locally and its geometric intuition
I'm just getting introduced to differential geometry of curves and surfaces, and I've come across this theoretical issue which I haven't been able to quite fully understand.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ and consider $\textbf{x}:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to\mathbb R^2$ a regular curve whose curvature is never $0$ and that is parametrized with the norm of the velocity being constant $1$. Since we're not really interested in the exact values of the geometrical objects of the curve, but more on properties like their sign (of the curvature, for example) and the geometric interpretation behind (wether the curve moves in a clockwise direction or not), then we can apply a movement and consider that: $\textbf{x}(0)=0,\textbf{x}'(0)=\textbf{e}_1=\textbf{t}_{\textbf{x}}(0)$ (tangent vector) and so
$\textbf{n}_{\textbf{x}}(0)=\textbf{e}_2$ (normal vector). Movements don't affect the properties we are interested in, more specifically, the 'form' of the curve we'd like to study (since translations and linear isometries don't). If $\kappa(t)$ is the curvature of our curve, we denote $\kappa_0:=\kappa_\textbf{x}(0) \neq 0, \kappa_0'=\kappa_\textbf{x}'(0)$. Then, we consider the Taylor's expansion of order $3$ centered in $0$ of our curve:
$$
\textbf{x}(s)=\textbf{x}(0)+s\textbf{x}'(0)+\frac{1}2s^2\textbf{x}''(0)
+\frac{1}6s^3\textbf{x}'''(0)+o(s^3).
$$
And given
$$
\textbf{x}'(0)=\textbf{t}_\textbf{x}(0)=\textbf{e}_1, 
\textbf{x}''(0)=\kappa_\textbf{x}(0)\textbf{n}_\textbf{x}(0)=\kappa_0\textbf{e}_2, \\
\textbf{x}'''(0)=-\kappa_\textbf{x}^2(0)\textbf{t}_\textbf{x}
(0)+\kappa_\textbf{x}'(0)\textbf{n}_\textbf{x}(0)=-\kappa_0^2\textbf{e}_1+\kappa_0'\textbf{e}_2
$$
(these are just an inmediate consequence from the Frenet equations), we have that:
$$
\textbf{x}(s)=s\left(1-\frac{\kappa_0^2}{6}s^2\right)\textbf{e}_1
+s^2\left(\frac{\kappa_0}{2}+\frac{\kappa_0'}{6}s\right)\textbf{e}_2+o(s^3)=
\begin{pmatrix} s \\ \frac{\kappa_0s^2}{2}\end{pmatrix} 
+ \frac{s^3}{6}\begin{pmatrix} \kappa_0^2 \\ \kappa_0' \end{pmatrix} + o(s^3).
$$
From this point, I don't really understand most of the geometric intuition and the properties behind the local form of the curve. For example, being $\kappa_0 \neq 0$, if $s$ is sufficiently small, then the curve does not go through the tangent line in $s=0$, but I don't really understand why, neither why depending on the sign of $\kappa_0$, the curve is located on the upper half-plane or not. Supposedly as well, if $\kappa_0<0$, the curve moves clockwise, otherwise ($\kappa_0>0$), it moves the other way. And also, locally, the curve resembles a parabola. This I see why, since if $s$ is small enough the other terms apart from the first vector on the last expression of $\textbf{x}(s)$:
\begin{pmatrix} s \\ \frac{\kappa_0s^2}{2}\end{pmatrix}
must be really small so we could ignore them, and this resembles the parametrization of a parabola (I'm not $100$% sure about this but I'd say the reason must be something along the lines).
And apart from this, are there any other properties we could highlight? What use does it have knowing about the local form of such curve? I think, for example, that this might help when studying the contact bewteen curves, since we only need to know about the surroundings of the point of intersection we're studying (and only derivatives are involved, of which we can know everything since the concept of differentation is local around the point we're interested in). Is there any other concept, object or relation between curves for which we can get important information just from a local point of view?
I must point out that this might be just a vague way to get into local theory of curves, but my main goal here is to have a solid idea and a correct intuition on the matter, as well as to have a better understanding on how curves behave locally around their points and the concepts that derive from it.

How can your curve be parametrized by arc length, if the parameter lives in $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$?

Sorry, it's wrongly phrased since we use the term "parametrized by the arc" to refer to the norm of the curve's velocity being constant 1, that's what I meant. I'll change it, thanks for pointing it out.

I see! A concise way to phrase this requirement would be "unit-speed curve" or "unit-speed parametrization".

Thank you, I'll take it into account when writing about it in English other times (I don't study Maths in English so sometimes I translate things directly and make mistakes like this one).
